# Why Is it better to use unreadable bytes for client server communication?

Tags: communication, server, protocol

I'm composing communication lyrics for client-server and what am I thinking about:

- "authme username passord" (maybe encrytped)
- "accept"
- "get archive of H2O from 03.02.2005 to 20.12.2064"
- transferring binary structure or "error descrtiption"

why I always need to do something like

- 0x0FA52FD + CRC
- 0x0D34423 + CRC
- ...

I can see some secure reasons but I think it's not the real reason so why I can't use strings in client-server communication?

Comment: "communication lyrics" - that needs to be made a technical term for something.

Comment: Yes, the idea of computers singing to each other has a certain appeal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would advocate a binary protocol based off something like [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/). There's little benefit, in my opinion, in a human-readable protocol assuming the protocol isn't *meant* to be read by a human.

Using protocol buffers gives you the compactness of a binary protocol with the flexibility of a text-based protocol (e.g. with optional fields and the like). It also has the added benefit of being able to generate the serialization/deserialization code for you automatically, so you can use strong-typed objects in your program code.

Comment: I don't transfer data in strings / commands only.

Comment: thank you for Protocol Buffers, maybe I will use it right now for my project. Seems interesting, and protobuf-net for client.

Comment: Even if the protocol isn't meant to be read by a human, at some point somebody is going to have to hack / troubleshoot / understand it and it is loads easier if it is text . . .

Comment: Although TCP/IP is reliable and 8-bit clean, some communications protocols may require sending data over a link which has neither property. Having a character or sequence which appears at the start of every message and nowhere else can be helpful when a link is unreliable, but would generally require that binary data which could contain such characters escape them. In some cases it may be easier to say that a protocol will always expand things by e.g. 33% than to say that data may expand by anywhere from 0% to 100%.

Answer (score 5):

you CAN use strings (look at the http, ftp, ... protocol) but then you'll likely bump into encoding problems (less now that the UTF8 has become the de facto standard but you'll still bump into stuff like UTF16 and will need to account for that)

you would also need to write a string parser that handles malformed input correctly (if only to drop the connection instead of crashing)

however parsing binary often comes down to a sequence of `switch(in&MASK){case FIRST_CASE:...}` which is much more efficient

however next to all these is the amount of data you are transmitting: binary can be much more compact than strings for comparable protocol

Comment: using UTF8 isn't a problem, writing normal parser / lexer is not a problem, same as parsing binary nodes, sure binary is more compact but I don't want to use strings for data, just foe commands. If I compare commands size with all other data it's no matters strings they are or binary symbols.

Comment: +1 for thinking about encodings for data (which affects binary protocols too), but -1 for thinking that constants in textual protocols need to be in anything other than a fixed encoding (_e.g._, ASCII).

Answer (score 4):

There are actually very few good reasons to go binary. The one you mentioned -- security -- is a false promise. You are either encrypting your data or not; binary transmission in the clear is still in the clear it just requires a modicum more skill to read. Another reason mentioned -- text encoding -- is effectively a solved problem at this point. On the flip side, binary encoding can create interesting problems -- think big- versus little-endian.

The advantages of text-based protocols are that they are vastly easier to understand, build, debug, use and hack. You don't need nearly as much tooling to get anywhere. When you do need tooling there is an endless array of text-based tools at your disposal. With your custom binary protocol you get to define the toolset for better of for worse.

This is not to say that binary protocols don't have their place -- there are lots of applications that require that sort of compactness and pointedness. But binary should not be the default answer.

Answer (score 2):

Do you *need* to maintain readability of the **protocol** itself? If so, why? Human-readable(that is, text strings) protocols like the example you gave have multiple downsides. First obvious one is the bandwidth requirements; it is surely much more compact to send out 0x01, 0x00 than something like "USER LOGIN\n", let alone longer phrases as you described. The second is security. For example what do the bytes 0x3C, 0x02 and 0x7F mean in terms of protocol? The only way to figure out is to start reverse-engineering the binaries. Much more tedious work, and not always that trivial.

Frankly, I see absolutely no real benefits of using human readable protocols, unless they are *specifically* ***meant*** *to be human readable* - something which I don't see happening that often. I would strongy advice against strings in protocols. Please, don't.

Comment: so because of size only? does size of commands such mutter? it's not easier for humans, it's easier for me to debug (just a bit).

Comment: Size matters all the time. Just because bandwidth "is unlimited"(for now, and for some it might not be at all) it doesn't mean you shouldn't preserve it. It's just a matter of "good practices", why would you waste something which you could easily conserve? I think finese is important, especially when we deal with communications. Minimizing overhead and "bloat" should be something to thrive for, because it affects everyone using the network.

Comment: It's been a while since I've worked in the guts of TCP/IP, but I don't think it's as simple as 'saving bandwidth'. As I recall TCP/IP is not going to waste a whole packet on transmitting a single byte or word unless specifically configured to do so (Nagle's algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle's_algorithm). Data is going to be buffered until it can fill up a packet. Using a more 'wasteful' representation may actually reduce command latency, as the buffers will fill up more quickly.

Comment: @youngdood Tell that to the veterans of [Y2K](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y2K).  There are **plenty** of good reasons to embrace "bloat".

Comment: @CharlesE.Grant Unless, of course, you force it to (_e.g._, setting the PUSH flag).  But your point is valid - a bit is pretty narrow at 1Gb/sec.

Comment: @Alessa Size can indeed matter, especially in bandwidth-constrained (_e.g._, [AX.25](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AX.25)) or -metered (_e.g._, non-4G mobile handsets) environments.

Answer (score 2):

The Internet has **lots** of experience with binary and textual protocols.  Textual protocols are the norm, not because "*we always do it that way*", but because over 40 years experience has shown that textual protocols are significantly easier to work with, and because bandwidth considerations rarely pan out in the long run.

Don't conflate "binary" and "secure".  There's nothing inherently secure about a binary protocol.  Even undocumented binary protocols have been reverse-engineered.  Similarly, there's nothing inherently insecure about a textual protocol.  Security arises from well-thought-out plans against attacks, not from simple obscurity.

Answer (score 1):

There are two reasons that spring to mind:

1. Encoded requests and responses are usually shorter than "plain text" requests. If you are sending a lot of data this *could* become important. It's less so these days with faster connections and if you are only sending relatively small amounts of data.
2. Security **is** a real concern. If requests and responses are sent in the clear they can be read while in transit (man in the middle attacks) and, given enough packets, your application could be compromised. People could send fake requests to get data out of your system, insert fake data into your system and generally make a mess of things. While this is also true for binary data, it's harder and less obvious what the data is.

Comment: about security: I understand but binary data is also hack-able in this way, just a bit more complex / harder.

Comment: @Alessa - That is true, I assumed you were talking about some sort of encoding/encrypting.

Comment: I'd phrase it more strongly: using a binary format vs. a text format does **not** improve security. It raises the *clue barrier* slightly, at most by providing obscurity. And as you surely have heard before: security through obscurity is not real security.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I wish my management could understand this. I currently have to implement an information maze around a product for the sake of IP protection, with the main consequence of making things awfully complicated.

Comment: a binary protocol does not offer any additional security by itself. You can send text over TLS just as easily as binary data.